# How to merge/concatenate two dataframe whose two columns with partially string matched?

Tags: python, pandas

I used Chicago crime data for my analysis, but there is no community name given, so I collected community name in chicago from online source. However, Redfin real estate data collected by Region/ neighborhood instead of community name. when I tried to merge prepossessed Chicago crime data with Redfin real estate data, I got merge error because Region name in Redfin data has partial string matching with Chicago crime data. I tried `regex` to do partial matching first then to merge two dataframe by year and name of community name.

Is there any solution for merging two dataframe whose columns yields partial string matching? can any one point me out? Thanks

**preprocessed data**:

here I create public gist for viewing data that I used:

[exampled data snippet on public gist](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/e43bde784cc1f63e1c2f3611ecbef343)

**my attempt**

```
pd.merge(chicago_crime, redfin, left_on='community_name', right_on='Region')
```

but this gives me a lot of `NAN` which means above concatenation is not correct. what should I do? any idea to make this right? thanks

Comment: You may want to check NLP clear your data then , merge

Comment: Have you tried `chicago_crime.merge(redfin, left_on='community_name', right_on='Region')` ?

Comment: @Yusufsn yes I did but I got empty dataframe, which is odd. Do you mind to take a look the data on the [data on the gist](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/e43bde784cc1f63e1c2f3611ecbef343)? Thank you

Comment: So you want to merge both dataframes based on different columns with partial data values?

Comment: @Yusufsn yes, do you have a better idea? would you mind review data on the gist? thanks for your help.

Comment: But, it would be possible that the key is not unique. For example in `chicago_crime` will have more than one `Chicago` as well as in `redfin`. How you deal with those data?

Comment: @Yusufsn I come up this solution, [neighborhood mapping](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/81a2b894a3ef48ba4d675f8ffcfe5584), can you take a look my solution?

Comment: @Yusufsn when I used your solution, it gives me this error: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`, `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`, why is that? how can I fix this? thank you

Comment: @Yusufsn can you help me to debug your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my approach. The first approach is applying `split()` to split each word in the key column in both dataframes.

```
chicago_crime['community_name'] = [cn.split() for cn in chicago_crime['community_name']]
redfin['Region'] = [rg.split() for rg in redfin['Region']]
```

Then I tried to compare each element in the resulted list of the column in `chicago_crime` with each element in the resulted list of the column in `redfin`. Then the matched elements are stored in a new column named `merge_ref` for both dataframes.

```
idx, datavalue = [], []
for i,dv in enumerate(chicago_crime['community_name']):
    for d in dv:
        if d in redfin['Region'][i]:   
            if i not in idx:
                idx.append(i)
                datavalue.append(d)
chicago_crime['merge_ref'] = datavalue
redfin['merge_ref'] = datavalue
```

Finally, merge both dataframes on `merge_ref`:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(chicago_crime[['community_area','community_name','merge_ref']], redfin, on='merge_ref')
```

However, since the values in `merge_ref` from both dataframe is not unique, the number of rows might increase. But at least, it gives you a hint.

**Updated**

Using your mapping solution:

```
### mapping neiborhood to community name

code_pairs_neighborhoods = [[p[0], p[1]] for p in [pair.strip().split('\t') for pair in neighborhood_Map.strip().split('\n')]]
neighborhood_name_dic = {k[0]:k[1] for k in code_pairs_neighborhoods} #neighborhood -> community area

chicago_crime['neighborhood'] = chicago_crime['community_name'].map(neighborhood_name_dic)
redfin['neighborhood'] = redfin['Region'].map(neighborhood_name_dic)

df_merge = pd.merge(chicago_crime, redfin, on='neighborhood')
print(df_merge)
```

Comment: to get rid of unnecessary duplication row, I come up this mapping neighborhood solution. Can you update your solution based on my [mapping solution](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/81a2b894a3ef48ba4d675f8ffcfe5584) ? thank you very much!

Comment: From your mapping solution, what if you reorder the list? Eg. `Chicago Lawn\tLithuanian Plaza` instead of `Lithuanian Plaza\tChicago Lawn`

Comment: is there any way we can integrate your solution with neighborhood mapping? because the current solution gave me an error. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the two datasets, it appears that `Chicago.Region` is of form `Chicago, IL - region_name` while `Redfin.community_name` is `region_name`. So I tried:

```
areas = ['Chicago, IL - ' + s for s in redfin.community_name.unique()] 

# check if areas in the chicago.Region
a = [s in chicago.Region.unique() for s in areas]
sum(a), len(a)
# 63, 77
```

which matches 63 of 77 areas in `redfin.community.unique()`. If it's good enough, you can do:

```
pd.merge(redfin, chicago, 
         left_on='Chicago, IL - ' + redfin.community_name, 
         right_on='Region')
```

Comment: many thanks for constant help. when I tried this solution to [actual data](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/e43bde784cc1f63e1c2f3611ecbef343), it gives me an error. would you mind look back the formulation of the above solution?